# Creating new instances with many to many relationship iterating over a dictionary DJANGO

Tags: python, django, for-loop, dictionary

I am new to Django. I try to create several instances of my two models pizza and toppings from a dictionary:

```
dictionary = dict()

dictionary[“Pizza1”] = (“A”,”B”,”C”)

dictionary[“Pizza2”] = () 

dictionary[“Pizza3”] = (“B”,”D”)
```

I want to relate them with a ManyToMany relationship so Pizza1 has A,B,C toppings but also Topping B can be in Pizza 1 and 3. My code is not somehow working, it gives me the three pizza instances (Pizza1,2,3) but all having all toppings (A,B,C,D) instead of only the ones that correspond. How can I fix it please? Thank you!

```
for pizza in dictionary:
    pizza_instance, created1 = Pizza.objects.get_or_create(name=pizza)
    if (len(dictionary[pizza])>0):
       for topping in dictionary[pizza]:
           topping_instance, created2 = Topping.objects.get_or_create(name=topping)
           pizza_instance.has_toppings.add(topping_instance)
           pizza_instance.save()
```

MODELS:

```
  class Topping (models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
 class Pizza (models.Model):     
    name = models.CharField (max_length=20)     
    has_toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the queryset ?

Comment: The DB is completely empty when I run my script. This is script is supposed to create the instances of the objects. I used get_or_create in case any it is repeated...

Comment: I second karthikr's question. How do you check what toppings pizzas have? Your code seems correct, so I wonder if you are not checking this the right way.

Comment: And by the way, you might want to only save pizza_instance once after all toppings are added and you don't really need the if statement.

Comment: I check it in the admin. When I click in one of the attributes of a Pizza is shows all the Toppings. Should be like this? I dont think so

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works for me:

```
for pizza in dictionary:
    pizza_instance, created1 = Pizza.objects.get_or_create(name=pizza)
    for topping in dictionary[pizza]:
        topping_instance, created2 = Topping.objects.get_or_create(name=topping)
        pizza_instance.has_toppings.add(topping_instance)
    pizza_instance.save()
```

To test:

```
>>> for p in Pizza.objects.all():
...     print(p.has_toppings.count())
... 
3
0
2
```

Comment: Same problem, it creates relationships for all pizzas with all topings... i dont know why

Comment: I tested your exact code setup with this (changed only the smart quotes to normal quotes + Pizza2 value to `tuple()` to make it valid) with Django 1.9, Python 3.4, Postgres DB and it works. See updated answer